# Celery ignores retry_backoff, instead retries 180 seconds repeatedly

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

Celery version number: `4.4.5`

I have a function decorated like so:

```
@app.task(bind=True, retry_backoff=5, retry_jitter=False, retry_kwargs={"max_retries": 5})
def foo(self):
    try:
        #work
     except Exception:
         try:
             _log.info(retrying task)
             self.retry()
         except MaxRetriesExceeded:
             _log.error(Permanent failure)
```

I would expect this to retry after 5 seconds, then again after 10, then again after 20, then 40, then 80.

Instead, celery logs 'retrying task after 180 seconds', which it does. It then repeats the same procedure twice to make three retries in total, before giving up.

From what I've read on the docs, this seems to be the correct way to do it. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6):

[`retry_backoff`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#Task.retry_backoff) option relates only to [autoretries](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-retry-for-known-exceptions) that you specify using `autoretry_for` task decorator parameter:

> A boolean, or a number. If this option is set to `True`, autoretries will be delayed following the rules of exponential backoff.

In your case, you are calling `self.retry()` yourself so the retry backoff doesn't apply.

**EDIT:**
To handle the cleanup actions after failure, consider this example:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

app = Celery(broker='pyamqp://')

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

def cleanup(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
    logger.error('An error has occured, cleaning up...')

@app.task(autoretry_for=(ZeroDivisionError,), retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 3},
          retry_backoff=True, on_failure=cleanup)
def fail():
    return 1/0
```

When you call the `fail` task, it will fail 3 times and then raise `ZeroDivisionError` exception. Also, it will call the `cleanup` function to do the cleanup. So you don't care if the task gets retried, you react to the fact the task failed and handle the fact accordingly in the `on_failure` callback. If your actions should depend on what exception occured, you can use the arguments the `cleanup` gets called with.

Comment: Ah, understood, thank you. So, how would I catch the MaxRetriesExceeded? If a task is not going to retry, I need to do some cleanup actions. I've edited the code to show an example.

Comment: @alex_halford What scenario do you refer to? Automatic retries or manually calling `retry()`? Anyway, I think that you shouldn't care about exceeded retries but about the fact that the task failed as that's the moment you should do the cleanup.

Comment: So if I want something like `retry_backoff ` for manual retries I'll have to calculate the countdown myself based on the number of retries? There's no exponential backoff helper of some sort?